# Why doesn't Entity translation show translated title in taxonomy term view?

Tags: i18n-l10n

My basic page content type is using **entity translation**. The language switcher works well when viewing the node. When observing a view that filters by taxonomy term, the node's title is always from it's initial language. ***How do I enable the contextually correct title to appear?***

Demonstrated here: http://45.79.167.134/drupal/skills-development. Notice the title remains the same while the summary changes based on language.

Also note that the link for the title is always for the original language's node.